# Touching ouside dialog activity - in which order the methods should be called?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an activity (lets say Activity A) from which I start another one (Activity B) with `android:theme="android:Theme.Dialog"` and this is not occupy the entire screen. On the second activity when touching on outside of this dialog activity I finish the activity.

I observed that when touching outside of Activity B first is called `onResume()` method of activity A and after that `onStop()` method of Activity B.

Maybe is a stupid question, but is this normal? I expected to be exactly opposite: first to be called `onStop()` method of activity B and after that `onResume()` method from activity A.